# Simple recursive object hierarchy in PHP, how to get ancestors avoiding infinite loop?

Tags: php, recursion, hierarchy, php-5.3, hierarchical

Property `parent` returns the parent of the current item (or `null`). I need to avoid infinite recursion with an item that it's parent of itself.

```php
// An item is considered without parent if parent is null or itself
$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setParent($item1);

$item2 = new Item();
$item2->setParent($item1);

$item3 = new Item();
$item3->setParent($item2);

$item1->getAncestors(); // Empty
$item2->getAncestors(); // Item 1
$item2->getAncestors(); // Item 1, Item 2
```

The following won't work because the first condition is `true` for "problematic" `$item` (thus the second isn't evaluated):

```php
/**
 * Gets all ancestors of this item, sorted in a way that the farthest ancestor
 * comes first.
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
public function getAncestors()
{
    $parent = $this;
    $ancestors = array();

    while ($parent = $parent->parent && $this !== $parent) {
        $ancestors[] = $parent;
    }

    return new ArrayCollection(array_reverse($ancestors));
}
```

This won't work too because on loop 1 `$this` is `$parent`:

```php
while ($this !== $parent && $parent = $parent->parent) {
    $ancestors[] = $parent;
}
```

I'm sure this is a common problem but I can't find a solution by myself.

Answer (score 0):

As you are stating it, the structure you are traversing is not a tree. It's a directed graph with cycles. One way to avoid an infinite loop is to keep track of the visited vertices by passing an arraylist containing all visited vertices. As you visit each vertex, you first check if it is in the list and return if true, add it to the list otherwise and continue. You do not need recursion. A while loop will do.

Comment: A child cannot have multiple parents, hence is a tree isn't it?

Comment: No, that's not a sufficient condition. You should not have any cycle. See  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_tree and related links for a formal definition of tree.

Comment: "A tree data structure can be defined recursively (locally) as a collection of nodes (starting at a root node), where each node is a data structure consisting of a value, together with a list of references to nodes (the "children"), with the constraints that no reference is duplicated, and none points to the root." (Wikipedia)

Comment: To the downvoter: Have the decency to leave a comment to explain.

Comment: I'm. I downvoted because, even if you are correct, this is not a code answer. It's a wikipedia link.

Comment: I fully described the algorithm to achieve what you need and I do not believe it is excessively complex. I also added explanations and references. Yet, you require spoon feeding and down-vote. Look, I am not paid by the hour. I am spending time benevolently to help. I got you closer to a solution, and I believe that deserves a minimum of respect. You could have nicely asked for more help after explaining that you were incapable of translating the provided algorithm into code. Good bye!